# SQL - Get all trips that User X and User Y rides together

Tags: sql

I have this model.

Trip hasMany Passenger through TripPassenger

TripPassenger belongs to Trip

TripPassenger belongs to User

User

How do get all trips that Passenger X takes along with Passenger Y?

Comment: Please add the schema of your table

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be a self-join:

```
select  tp1.TripId
from    TripPassenger tp1
join    TripPassenger tp2
on      tp1.UserId = X
        and tp2.UserId = Y
        and tp1.TripId = tp2.TripId
```

Comment: Actually this is the only possible solution in my opinion. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

```
select trip_id
from trip_passenger
where passenger_id in (1,2)
group by trip_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This will return those trips where exactly those two passengers took part. If you wnat those where other passengers participated as well, you need to use `count(*) >= 2`.

I also assumes that no passenger is assigned twice to the same trip.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TripID
FROM TripPassenger
WHERE User = @User1
  AND TripID IN (
    SELECT TripID
    FROM TripPassenger
    WHERE User = @User2
  )
```